# Load ABRecordRef from ABRecordID in iOS

Tags: ios, abrecord, abrecordref

I'm storing an array of `ABRecordID` (actually wrapped in NSNumber) into `NSUserDefaults`. So far so good but now I need to load those into `ABRecordRef` and can't find what function to use.

I'm just looking for the function that creates the ABRecordRef from an ABRecordID, that's all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found it!

```
ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(ABAddressBookRef addressBook, ABRecordID recordID);
```